# Turn [file-format] into [data-format]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 27 [file-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) questions. Only four of those questions have the term "file format" in the title, whereas six include the broader term "data format".

The way I see it, [file-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) is a subset of [data-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-format). As an example, if I ask about an API that returns data in different formats, I'd say the [data-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-format) tag would fit perfectly, whereas [file-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) feels a little awkward, since the data might never get saved into an actual file.

What do you think? Are there any reasons for keeping the [file-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) tag instead of a broader [data-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-format) tag?

Comment: good idea (comment is long enough now)

Comment: Good idea! By the way, how about just "format"?

Comment: I like the idea of [tag:format] because it's shorter and doesn't have the rather redundant "data" in it. On the other hand, it could be less clear and more ambiguous than [tag:data-format]. What do others think?

Comment: i think you're right about data format > file format and that format is too vague

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the feedback! I have changed the tag from [file-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) to [data-format](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-format) and updated the tag wiki accordingly.